# How to clean up poorly formed HTML using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, html-agility-pack

I am attempting to replace this god awful collection of regular expressions that is currently used to clean up blocks of poorly formed HTML and stumbled upon the HTML Agility Pack for C#.  It looks very powerful but yet, I couldn't find an example of how I want to use the pack which, in my mind, would be a desired functionality included in it.  I am sure I am an idiot and cannot find a suitable method in the documentation.

Let me explain... say I had the following html:

```
<p class="someclass">
    <font size="3">
        <font face="Times New Roman">
            this is some text
            <a href="somepage.html">Some link</a>
        </font>
    </font>
</p>
```

... that I want to look like:

```
<p>
    this is some text
    <a href="somepage.html">Some link</a>
</p>
```

When I utilize the HtmlNode.Remove() method it removes the node plus all it's children.  Is there a way to remove the node preserving the children?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On HtmlNode, the method RemoveChild has this overload:

```
public HtmlNode RemoveChild(HtmlNode oldChild, bool keepGrandChildren);
```

So this is how you would do it:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("yourfile.htm");

foreach (HtmlNode font in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//font"))
{
    font.ParentNode.RemoveChild(font, true);
}
```

**EDIT:** It looks like the Replace w/ keepGrandChildren option is not working as expected, so here is an alternate implementation:

```
public static HtmlNode RemoveChild(HtmlNode parent, HtmlNode oldChild, bool keepGrandChildren)
{
    if (oldChild == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("oldChild");

    if (oldChild.HasChildNodes && keepGrandChildren)
    {
        HtmlNode prev = oldChild.PreviousSibling;
        List<HtmlNode> nodes = new List<HtmlNode>(oldChild.ChildNodes.Cast<HtmlNode>());
        nodes.Sort(new StreamPositionComparer());
        foreach (HtmlNode grandchild in nodes)
        {
            parent.InsertAfter(grandchild, prev);
        }
    }
    parent.RemoveChild(oldChild);
    return oldChild;
}

// this helper class allows to sort nodes using their position in the file.
private class StreamPositionComparer : IComparer<HtmlNode>
{
    int IComparer<HtmlNode>.Compare(HtmlNode x, HtmlNode y)
    {
        return y.StreamPosition.CompareTo(x.StreamPosition);
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising with one problem.  It reverses the order of the grandchildren from the original.

Comment: @nokturnal - good catch! hhmmm. looks like a bug to me. I have updated my answer.

Comment: This looks like the right answer, but there are some flaws in the HTML Agility Pack with is probably going to lead me away from it for this project.

Comment: The first solution (before the *EDIT*) seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp) instead.

```
var parser = new HtmlParser();
var document = parser.Parse(html);

using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    document.ToHtml(writer, new PrettyMarkupFormatter());
    return writer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Totally an amazing lib (as was it's pseudo-predecessor csquery), and I would totally recommend this now... it just didn't  exist in 2011 :)

Comment: Currently, instead of `parser.Parse` you should use `parser.ParseDocument`.

Answer (score -1):

Once you find the

element use the InnerText method to get the text, Then do the remove and then insert the text.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my HTML examples were too simplistic.  It needs to copy more than the InnerText to the parent element.  Please see my revised / edited examples.