# DLL not found error after publishing in VS2015 — tidy.x64.dll

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, tidy, htmltidy

I have an issue I struggle with since days. I nearly tried everything i am able to try but had no success. Not to hide, I am not an C# expert but I use to learn.

I use TidyHTML in a project to correct some corrupt html from an editor. The software is written in C#, .net 4.6. We publish to an FTP-Server (One Click)

I started with TidyHtml5ManagedRepack and TidyHtml5Managed from nuget. Formerly i compiled 32bit. When i tried to change over to 64bit i was no more able to reinstall TidyHtml5ManagedRepack from nuget. So i installed it manually (referencing).

On my development machine (Win7 with 64bit) everything is good when i compile 64bit or 32bit.

TidyHtml5Managed.dll is in "References-folder" and added to References.
tidy.x86.dll and tidy.x64.dll are in the projects root folder and while release they got copied.

This works on my development machine AND on windows 7 client machines.

**When i try to install it on windows 10 64 bit (installation works well and software starts) i get this error for x64 compilation:**

> System.DllNotFoundException: Die DLL "tidy.x64.dll": Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden. (Ausnahme von HRESULT:
>   0x8007007E) kann nicht geladen werden.

**But the dll exists in the root folder**. I also tried to copy it to windows-folder and other folder where it could be loaded from. Maybe the delivered x64-dll is not compatible to win10? Is this possible?

I tried also to use tidy dll for 64bit from here; http://binaries.html-tidy.org/. Just renamed it to tidy.x64.dll an renamed in the root-apps folder on clinet machine (win10). Same error.

Does anyone have an idea or a suggested setup for this issue? I want use my software in 64bit with tidy.

Comment: Grüße zurück. Try ensuring that the correct [MSVC redists](https://entwicklergate.de/t/liste-aktueller-und-aelterer-downloads-von-visual-c-runtime-paketen/325?u=uwekeim) are installed.

Comment: Or, use [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and/or my own [port of Google's HTML Compressor library](https://github.com/UweKeim/ZetaProducerHtmlCompressor).

Comment: Deploying only tidy.x64.dll is not enough, you must also include the DLLs that it needs.  They are not included in the binary download available from html-tidy.org.  You didn't say which one you used, but vcruntime140.dll is a pretty safe bet.  If the target machine is ancient and not being maintained then running Windows Update is also necessary to get the UCRT.

Comment: i now installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2017 64bit on the client machine but nothing changed. Here is a simple screenshot of the error.

@HansPassant should i just add vcruntime140.dll to the root folder?

Comment: I was wondering why you never mentioned tiny.dll.  Renaming the file is not a grand idea.  Use the debugger on your own machine, enabled unmanaged debugging with Project > Properties > Debug.  You get load notifications for all the DLLs that your program uses in the Output window.  Debug > Windows > Modules shows them as well, after you run any managed method that uses tidy.

Comment: @UweKeim does your port or HTML agility pack any corrections on the html code? I use tidy to do some correction of missing closing-tags in html. This works very well.

Comment: Html Agility Pack should do this, too. Just give it a try.

Comment: @HansPassant TidyHtml5ManagedRepack from nuget comes with tiny.x64.dll and tiny.x86.dll. There is no tiny.dll. I see, in distributions of the main sources of tiny, you download the tiny.dll. Are they managed? i will try.

Comment: You could also use https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313797/107625

Comment: Well, that's quite a crappy home page for that nuget package.  Dumpbin.exe /imports on tidy.x64.dll shows that it has a dependency on msvcr100.dll.  That's the C runtime for VS2010 projects, just copy it from c:\windows\system32 on your machine into the same directory as your .exe file on the target machine.

Comment: @HansPassant as usual here i have to say "you saved my live" :)

This worked. I will add the dll to my project and configure to export it to the output folder as well. I will share my experience with this here.

Can ou please post it as solution so i can mark it as one? Many thanks!

Comment: @UweKeim i began to implement agility pack but as i can say from my first researches, it is much more complex to repair broken html in htmlagility then in tidy.

In Tidy you just say: doc.CleanAndRepair();

Comment: Put msvcr100.dll to the project and configure it to copy to the output folder. This works like a charm! Thank you @HansPassant

Answer (score 0):

@HansPassant thank you for your comment.  Simply installing the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) in Windows (https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=5555) was my solution.

The other option as Hans says is to include the msvcr100.dll with your executable and then you don't need the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package installed.  But  make sure it is the correct msvcr100.dll.  To be sure you have the correct one install the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package first, get it from either C:\Windows\SysWOW64 or C:\Windows\system32, then you can uninstall the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package again.